# Menu css separado por barra

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```
<ul>
  <li>Inicio</li>
  <li>Notícias</li>
  <li>Download</li>
  <li>Contatos</li>
</ul>
```

Gostaria de tornar isso uma lista horizontal separada por um carácter de barra **|**, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

Para isso você vai usar css. O código é o seguinte:

```
 ul li {
    display: inline;
}

li:before {
content: " | ";
}

li:first-child:before {
content: none;
}
```

O exemplo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/130fLe69/)

Comment: Perfeita resposta, creio nem precisar complementar.

Answer (score 1):

Veja é isso... com barra por horizontal.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;  
}

ul li:last-child {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Inicio</li>
  <li>Notícias</li>
  <li>Download</li>
  <li>Contatos</li>
</ul>
```